# Clang format with weird enums

Tags: c++, clang-format

Does anyone knows what options can I use in clang format to allow the following behaviour:

```
enum class Cells {
    A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, F1, G1, H1,
    A2, B2, C2, D2, E2, F2, G2, H2,
    A3, B3, C3, D3, E3, F3, G3, H3,
    A4, B4, C4, D4, E4, F4, G4, H4,
    A5, B5, C5, D5, E5, F5, G5, H5,
    A6, B6, C6, D6, E6, F6, G6, H6,
    A7, B7, C7, D7, E7, F7, G7, H7,
    A8, B8, C8, D8, E8, F8, G8, H8,
};
```

With the current settings, it is formatting with one entry per line:

```
enum class Cells {
    A1,
    B1,
    C1,
    ...
};
```

Comment: Have you considered disabling formatting for the section as an option?

Comment: @stefan you should write this as an answer. It is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

As @Eljay said: "// clang-format off before the enum block, and // clang-format on afterward."

Edit: I can only mark as answered in two days

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid the only specific option is `AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine`

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Thats the only alternative I could come across - case of a short enum on a single line.

Comment: `// clang-format off` before the enum block, and `// clang-format on` afterward.

Comment: @Eljay Oh I see, just code it manually and flag it. Thats a good idea.

Comment: @Eljay its actually a better idea. You should have written as an answer.

Comment: It was stefan's idea (above comment).  I looked up the syntax out of curiosity.